# Create Swagger-docs for API written in Express 4.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

I have a server written with Node and Express 4. I also have a customer which wants this to be documented with Swagger. How can this be done?

I've looked into the following tools:

- [swagger-node-express](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node): Lets you do exactly what I want, except it does not support Express 4.x
- [Swagger 2.0 - Node-Express-4.x](https://github.com/omninews/swagger-2.0-node-express-4.x): Same as above but with a different approach. Could be used, except I don't find much documentation on setting it up (and I'm too slow to get it without docs)

Tools like [swaggerize-express](https://github.com/krakenjs/swaggerize-express) and [Swaggers own tool for Node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) would work if I started from scratch, but I just want a way to easiliy add docs to my project so that Swagger can read it.

It wouldn't work in the long run to write a doc-file that Swagger can read because then I'd have to update it. I want to document everything in the code and not a Swagger- or readme-file, and let the documentation be available through a Swagger-UI automatically.

I may have overlooked something here, but I can't seem to find anything to help me.All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend looking into [Loopback](http://loopback.io/) framework. It's framework for creating REST APIs on stereoids. It is using Express under the hood and is created by company StrongLoop, which also maintains [Express project](https://github.com/strongloop/express) itself now.

**It supports Swagger out of the box.**

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this means starting from the beginning, which is the same that the Swagger-CLI requires. I want to implement self-documentation in an already existing project.

Comment: Hmm than I gues looking into Loopback code would give you nice hints. As they are having Swagger integrated and are using Express. At least it would give you hint which library to use.